# what is the variable 'C' refers to in Big O or Omega notation

Tags: big-o

In Big O or Omega notation, I understand that n refers to the input to the program. But what is the variable C refers to?

Comment: Can you please put it in context? Where did you see `C`? How was it used?

Comment: I was going through a material for Big O notation and I found this snippet.. **f(n) = c g(n)** where n is the input to the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's hard to answer this question without knowing where you saw a `C` in discussion of big O notation, I suspect it was used to represent a constant of some kind.

For instance, you can use `C` in translating a statement using Big-O notation to a statement using predicate logic terminology:

> `f(x) = O(g(x))` means:
>
> There exist positive real numbers `C` and `x0`, such that for all `x >= x0`, `f(x) <= C * g(x)`

The choice of `C` for the name of the constant multiple here is completely arbitrary. `C` is probably popular simply because it's the first letter of "constant". At most, it's a convention.

You could use some other letter and the meaning would be the same. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) on the topic (at the time I'm writing this) uses `M` in most of its equations (though `C` sneaks into a few of them further down the page). It's entirely possible you saw `C` in one description of big-O notation, but then read some other description of it that didn't use `C` at all.

Comment: So can i assume that the constant 'C' represents the number of constant operations like adding value to variable.

Comment: No, there's no real meaning attached to the `C`; it is arbitrary. Often many different `C` values would work. The point of big-O notation is that you don't need to care about the constant multiple. If you need an precise count of operations, not just an asymptotic bound, you shouldn't use big-O notation.